# How to Save Gradient Boosting Regressor Results to File?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a Gradient Boosting Regressor model for which I would like to save the results to a csv.

```
from sklearn import ensemble
clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators = 400, max_depth = 5, min_samples_split = 2,
          learning_rate = 0.1, loss = 'squared_error')
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I would like to see the actuals and predicted values.

Comment: So you want to save `y_test`  and/or `y_train` and it's prediction?

Comment: ImSo3K, that is correct. I am assuming that I can see the actual value, the predicted value, and from there calculate the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fitting your model, you need to actually `predict` the predictions, with `clf.predict`, lets say that we want to save `y_pred_train` & `y_pred_test`:

```
y_pred_train = clf.predict(y_train)
y_pred_test = clf.predict(y_test)
```

Now that we have both predicted values and the actual ones for both `train` & `test` sets, we can save a `.csv` file with [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
np.savetxt("train_preds.csv", np.column_stack((y_train, y_pred_train)), delimiter=",", fmt='%.5f')
```

And

```
np.savetxt("test_preds.csv", np.column_stack((y_test, y_pred_test)), delimiter=",", fmt='%.5f')
```

We are using `np.column_stack` just to stack them as columns rather as rows since they are 1D numpy arrays in their nature.

**Please Note** that I formatted the floating point precision just for visibility purposes, if you are going to calculate the loss afterwards it's better not to format at all.

Comment: ImSo3K, thank you. How do I also get the column headers to export?

Comment: You can add the `header="actual,prediction", comments=''` parameters to the `np.savetxt` method, the `header` parameter is a string with your headers separated by comma, and `comments` is used to delete the `#` that will be produced before the first column that marks it as comment